# `DIR /B /O:N > filename.txt` but only showing folders without a certain file

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, dir

I'm trying to make a list in XP of folders which do not contain a `.jpg` file.

I use `DIR /B /O:N > filename.txt` for making a folder list. It works perfectly, but now I need a list where the folders without a certain file type is listed.

Is it possible?

Comment: This does not explain how to show folders not contaning a specific file

Answer (score 0):

```
(for /d %a in (*) do @if not exist "%~fa\*.jpg" echo %~nxa) > folderList.txt
```

For each folder, if not exist a jpg file inside it, echo the name of the folder.

To use it inside a batch file, remember to escape the percent signs, that is, replace `%` with `%%`